# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named available

Tags: java, spring

Почему спринг не может найти бин savingAccount1 когда я пытаюсь добавить его в лист для client1?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="savingAccount1 " class="com.luxoft.bankapp.model.SavingAccount">
    <constructor-arg name="initialBalance" value="1000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="checkingAccount1" class="com.luxoft.bankapp.model.CheckingAccount">
    <property name="overdraft" value="1000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="checkingAccount2" class="com.luxoft.bankapp.model.CheckingAccount">
    <property name="overdraft" value="1500"/>
</bean>

<bean id="client1" class="com.luxoft.bankapp.model.Client">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="Jonny Bravo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="gender">
        <value type="com.luxoft.bankapp.model.Client$Gender">MALE</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="repository" ref="repository"/>
    <property name="accounts">
        <list>
            <ref bean="savingAccount1"/>
            <ref bean="checkingAccount1"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="client2" class="com.luxoft.bankapp.model.Client">
    <constructor-arg name="name" value="Adam Budzinski"/>
    <constructor-arg name="gender">
        <value type="com.luxoft.bankapp.model.Client$Gender">MALE</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="repository" ref="repository"/>
    <property name="accounts">
        <list>
            <ref bean="checkingAccount2"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Логи с ошибкой

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'client1' defined in class path resource [test-clients.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'savingAccount1' while setting bean property 'accounts' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'savingAccount1' available
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'client1' defined in class path resource [test-clients.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'savingAccount1' while setting bean property 'accounts' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'savingAccount1' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:95)
    at BankApplication.main(BankApplication.java:23)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'savingAccount1' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:805)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1279)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в applicationContext.xml <context:annotation-config />
Если не поможет - скиньте исходный код классов